# Log4J2: define custom level in log4j2.properties file

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

this is my log4j2.properties:

```
rootLogger.level = ALL

customLevels = V
customLevel.V.name = VERBOSE
customLevel.V.intLevel = 525

property.filename = trace.log
property.msgcolor = FATAL=BG_Yellow Red Bright, ERROR=Red, WARN=Yellow Bold, INFO=Green, DEBUG=BG_Magenta Yellow, TRACE=blue

appenders = R, console

appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = STDOUT
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = [%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %highlight{%level}{${msgcolor}} %c{1}:%L]: %highlight{%msg}{${msgcolor}}%style{%n}{Default Normal}%throwable

appender.R.type = RollingFile
appender.R.name = File
appender.R.fileName = ${filename}
appender.R.filePattern = ${filename}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}
appender.R.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.R.layout.disableAnsi = true
appender.R.layout.noConsoleNoAnsi = true
appender.R.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
appender.R.policies.type = Policies
appender.R.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.R.policies.size.size = 20MB

rootLogger.appenderRefs = R, console

rootLogger.appenderRef.console.ref = STDOUT
rootLogger.appenderRef.R.ref = File
```

I expect that following code

```
customLevels = V
customLevel.V.name = VERBOSE
customLevel.V.intLevel = 525
```

add a new custom level named VERBOSE and with intLevel value set to 525, but it doesn't take any effects. Why?

Comment: customLevels.V.name instead of customLevel.V.name perhaps?

Comment: @RAZ_Muh_Taz, No, I just tried. I think it should be as for appenders:
appenders = APPENDER1, APPENDER2, ...
|
appender.APPENDER1.name = ...
|
etc...

Answer (score 2):

Use below in ur log4j2.properties:
customLevel.VERBOSE=525

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar issue, it works when we configure log4j2 properties using xml file and having issue when we have these properties in log4j2.properties file.

solution for now would be as below, where you mention custom level name directly and remove customerLevel.v.name property.   This is until log4j2 fixes this issue.

simple solution: add below properties. for quick check, you can give the values as 1 instead for 525, 1 means it will log every time.

customLevels = VERBOSE
customLevel.VERBOSE = 525

Comment: The currently supported syntax is `customLevel.VERBOSE = 525`. Also `customLevels` is ignored, all properties that start with `customLevel.` are registered.